# Why does the filename extension make a difference to compiling?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I compile this code under CentOs8 with the GNU compiler:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *a = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

When I name it **a.cpp**, both of the compile commands failed:

```
g++ -o a a.cpp
gcc -o a a.cpp
```

But after I rename it to **a.c**, this compile command succeeds:

```
gcc -o a a.c
```

This is C code, NOT C++ code. I believe using `gcc` or `g++` should make the difference, but it seems the compiler only considers the filename extension.

Could you please provide some details on this?

Comment: In C++, you have to cast the result of `malloc` because C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion to and from `void *`. Try `int* a = (int*) malloc(3*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Also, `<stdlib.h>` is a C header file. In C++, it is `<cstdlib>` instead.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `malloc()` should not be used in C++ at all, use `new` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am aware of this, but OP has explicitly stated "this is a C code, NOT a c++ code." so I thought this was mainly C code that could have maybe used in a few C++ files too.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 -- implicit conversions **to** `void*` are allowed in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ is going to error on your implicit cast from the `void*` returned by `malloc()` to `int*`.  Whereas C allows implicit casts from `void*` to other pointer types.

Most compilers will default to looking at the file extension to determine language to compile to.

A `man gcc` reveals that all `.c` files default to being compiled as `C`.  Whereas all `.cc`, `.cp`, `.cxx`, `.cpp`, `.CPP`, `.c++`, and `.C` (capital C) files are compiled as `C++`.

You can override this behavior force the language via the `-x` option for gcc/g++.

Example:

```
 gcc -x c++ foo.c -c   // compiles foo.c as C++ instead of C
```

gcc and g++ are typically the same binary on most unix systems. It just defaults to different behavior depending on its own `argv[0]` parameter.

There might be other behavior differences between explicitly using g++ and gcc versus the `-x` option. I'm not certain on that.

Comment: `g++` adds additional linker flags for the standard library, `gcc` doesn't even if compiling a cpp file

Comment: `gcc` uses the compiler extension to determine if the file is C or C++ (or others).  That association can be overridden by using `-std=c99`.

Comment: @Eljay - what's a "compiler extension" ?

Comment: `*.cpp` or `*.cxx` or `*.cc` or `*.C` is assumed C++; `*.c` is assumed C; `*.m` is assumed to be Objective-C, `*.mm` is assumed to be Objective-C++; `*.s` is assumed to be Assembly.  (This is not an exhaustive list.)  The GCC compiler (and other compilers as well) use the file name's extension as a metadata clue as to the language the source is in, unless the language is provided to the toolchain driver (`gcc` or `g++` are toolchain drivers that invoke preprocessor, compiler, linker, et cetera) explicitly.

Comment: @Eljay - I think you missed my point.  I think you meant to say **file** extension, not **compiler** extension. ;)

Comment: Too late to edit the old comment, alas.  It will stand as a testament for all time.